# How write 'Ñ' in a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that the encoding can be declared this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But when i try to write 'ñ' in a file, is write 'Ã' instead.

I also try of this way (like is write [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) in the docs)

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open('output', encoding='utf-8')
f.write("ñÑ")
```

but it raise:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `codecs.open()`, producing a file object that expects *`unicode` objects*. You are, however, passing in a byte string, so Python has to decode to `unicode` first using the default ASCII codec. This is why you get a *decoding* error where the ASCII codec failed to decode your UTF-8 bytes.

Decode your string, use a `unicode` string literal, or use `open()` instead of `codecs.open()`.

Each of these will work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
with codecs.open('output', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(u"ñÑ")
```

or

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
with codecs.open('output', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("ñÑ".decode('utf8'))
```

or

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
with open('output') as f:
    f.write("ñÑ")
```

`codecs.open()` does take a codec, but that tells the file object how to encode `unicode` objects to bytes.

Comment: thank's for the help. I have the output in a variable, so i try this way:
with codecs.open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(cont.decode("utf8"))
And it raise: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2273: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @RicardoBello: then your data is not valid UTF-8 data. Perhaps it is using a different codec?

Comment: I'm building the content using the letters from string module but adding the ñ and Ñ of this way: letters = string.letters.replace("N","NÑ").replace("n","nñ"). I run the code without adding those letters and all ok. Perhaps that is causing the exception

Comment: @Ricardo: are you 100% certain you saved your source code as UTF8 and used the `coding: utf-8` comment?

Comment: @Ricardo: I can't quite conceive of a scenario where the `str.replace()` methods would create a byte stream where the UTF-8 bytes end up scrambled the way your error message indicates. That said, both `ñ` and `Ñ` consist of two bytes in UTF-8 where the first byte is C3 so there does appear to be a relationship.

Comment: @Ricardo: for example, running your `string.letters` replacement on 2.7 produces entirely expected results: http://ideone.com/t8p4Rt

Comment: see my code in dpaste: http://dpaste.com/2974FHB I'm building a script for create a web page using all browser safe fonts for after create a dataset of those letters (so you understand the code) forgive my poor english. . .

Comment: @RicardoBello your Pastie code doesn't use `codecs.open()` so why use `str.decode()`?

Comment: @RicardoBello I see the issue. You are looping over individual *bytes*. Not over letters; UTF8 uses between 1 and 4 bytes per letter; the ñ and Ñ letters consist of two bytes each in UTF8 and your loop treats those separately. Use Unicode objects throughout instead as looping over Unicode strings gives you the whole codepoint.

Comment: Thank's i think i need to learn about Unicode objects, str and encodings. . .

Answer (score 1):

Try `fwrite(u'ñ')`
The u before the string makes it a different kind of string...