# how to write ñ instead strange simbols on folder files wihle using os.mkdir

Tags: python, python-os

i am trying to copy files but i use the ñ simbol when i

```
 os.mkdir(TOP_DATA + name)
```

where name can contain the ñ simbol, the problem is that when i search for the folder in the browser i get things like  MUÃ‘OZ  and this kind of simbols(it should said muñoz) the way that i import the database is this

```
df_faces = pd.read_csv("/home/workstation/Desktop/fv/data estructurada/DB_cleaned_barandilla.csv",encoding="latin-1", index_col=0)
```

any advice to solve this would be great!

Comment: You can check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291524/how-write-%c3%91-in-a-file-using-python

Comment: it would work with 'utf-8'??

Comment: The answer to the question says so